# I can't get Angular materials to work with Angular 5

Tags: angular

I've ran into a couple of problems using angular materials and now i'm stuck.
I've gotten angular materials to play nice with the rest of angular. However, on every `npm start` command i'm getting the warning

```
@angular/compiler-cli@5.0.2 requires typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.5.0' but 2.6.1 was found instead.
Using this version can result in undefined behaviour and difficult to debug problems.

Please run the following command to install a compatible version of TypeScript.

    npm install typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.5.0'

To disable this warning run "ng set warnings.typescriptMismatch=false".
```

When I do this command it says 'file not found' When I run the command npm install typescript@2.4.2 it says it installs it but on the next npm start I get the same mismatch error again.

Furthermore when I try to render the page that contains a angular materials table it doesn't render anything and instead gives me the error

```
Error: Unexpected directive 'MatPaginator' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "webapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "typescript": "^2.6.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.2",
    "typescript": "~2.6.1"
  }
}
```

and this is my appModule

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AccountCreateComponent} from './account/create/account-create.component';
import {AccountListComponent} from './account/list/account-list.component';
import {AccountUpdateComponent} from './account/update/account-update.component';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {LeaveCreateComponent} from './leave/create/leave-create.component';
import {LeaveListComponent} from './leave/list/leave-list.component';

import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';
import {RestApiService} from "./rest-api.service";
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
import {LeavePendingListComponent} from './leave/pending-list/leave-pending-list.component';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import {MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource} from "@angular/material";
import {MaterialModule} from "./MaterialModule";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    AccountCreateComponent,
    AccountUpdateComponent,
    AccountListComponent,
    LeaveCreateComponent,
    LeaveListComponent,
    LeavePendingListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
      BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpModule,
    MatPaginator,
    MatTableDataSource  
  ],
  providers: [RestApiService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?

EDIT: I've resolved part of the problems by making a separate MaterialsModule and importing that MaterialsModule into the appModule.

```
import {
    MatAutocompleteModule, MatButtonModule, MatButtonToggleModule, MatCardModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatChipsModule,
    MatDatepickerModule, MatDialogModule, MatExpansionModule, MatGridListModule, MatIconModule, MatInputModule,
    MatListModule, MatMenuModule, MatNativeDateModule, MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule, MatRippleModule, MatSelectModule, MatSidenavModule, MatSliderModule, MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule, MatStepperModule, MatTableModule, MatTabsModule, MatToolbarModule, MatTooltipModule
} from "@angular/material";
import {A11yModule} from "@angular/cdk/a11y";
import {BidiModule} from "@angular/cdk/bidi";
import {ObserversModule} from "@angular/cdk/observers";
import {OverlayModule} from "@angular/cdk/overlay";
import {PlatformModule} from "@angular/cdk/platform";
import {PortalModule} from "@angular/cdk/portal";
import {ScrollDispatchModule} from "@angular/cdk/scrolling";
import {CdkStepperModule} from "@angular/cdk/stepper";
import {CdkTableModule} from "@angular/cdk/table";
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
/**
 * Created by maurice on 22-11-2017.
 */
@NgModule({
    exports: [
        // CDK
        A11yModule,
        BidiModule,
        ObserversModule,
        OverlayModule,
        PlatformModule,
        PortalModule,
        ScrollDispatchModule,
        CdkStepperModule,
        CdkTableModule,

        // Material
        MatAutocompleteModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatButtonToggleModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatChipsModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatExpansionModule,
        MatGridListModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatProgressBarModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatRadioModule,
        MatRippleModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatSlideToggleModule,
        MatSliderModule,
        MatSnackBarModule,
        MatStepperModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatTabsModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        MatNativeDateModule,
    ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

Comment: Well if wanted to use Paginator, you forgot to add it back to you AppModule. Initially you were getting the error because you importing **MatPaginator** instead of **MatPaginatorModule**.

Answer (score 0):

The warning can be resolve with

```
npm install -D typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.5.0'
npm install --save typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.5.0'
```

Depending on where the dependency is (in your case, use `--save`)

Now for Material : did you follow the guide step by step to install it ?

About your other error, is your component declared in the same module where you import all the material modules ?

Comment: when I run the command npm install -D typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.5.0' I get the error message The system cannot find the file specified. The same message appears when I run your second command. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I can't even find your error on Google. Maybe try re-installing NPM again ?

Comment: see my edit. I've included a MaterialModule with a whole bunch of unnecessary modules, only to find out that the real stuff that was missing were the cdk related modules. The guide on material.angular.io is incomplete because they don't mention anything about importing AllyModule or BidiModule for example.

Comment: Well that was the point of the second part of my answer. But did you resolve your NPM issue ?

Comment: no. I get a message saying 'The system cannot find the file specified' whenever I try out one of your npm commands

Comment: Did you re install NPM ?

Comment: wish I could say no in 13 characters... oh wait, that's no longer neccessairy now is it. What I ment to say was 'no'. But I do like to thank you for the effort of answering my questions. I've got my mat-table working now. Cheers

Comment: That's all that matters !